# Cannot consume from Kafka Topic using confluent-kafka-python to a new consumer-group

Tags: python, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I am trying to consume from a Kafka Topic using confluent-kafka-python to a brand-new consumer-group(GROUP_NAME_CONNECT5 in the sample shown below). It does not seem to work unless I first consume using the kafka-console-consumer using this new consumer-group ! After I consume using the kafka-console-consumer just 1-time, then the confluent-kafka-python consumer works fine !! Any idea why ?

## Properties:

[Kafka]

bootstrap_servers=

ssl_ca_location=

max_wait_cycles=30

group_name=GROUP_NAME_CONNECT5

client_id=CLIENT_ID

auto_commit_interval_ms=5000

## Code:

```
kafkaConsumerConfig = {
    'bootstrap.servers': config.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS,
    'group.id': config.GROUP_NAME,
    'client.id': config.CLIENT_ID,
    'session.timeout.ms': 60000,
    'heartbeat.interval.ms': 3000,

    'security.protocol': 'SASL_SSL',
    'sasl.kerberos.service.name': 'kafka',

    'sasl.mechanisms': 'GSSAPI',
    'ssl.ca.location': config.SSL_CA_LOCATION,
    'sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd': 'kinit -S {0} {1} -k -t {2}'.format(config.KEYTAB_PRINCIPAL, config.KEYTAB_USER, config.KEYTAB_PATH),
    'default.topic.config': {
        'enable.auto.commit': 'false',
        'enable.auto.offset.store': 'false'
    }

c = Consumer(**self.kafkaConsumerConfig)

c.subscribe([self.TOPIC_NAME])

while True:
    kafka_msg = c.poll(1.0)
    process_message(kafka_msg)
```

## Logs: after running the Python Consumer for 5 minutes (and then killed it). The Python-consumer was not able to consume any messages !

%7|1579623452.300|INIT|CLIENT_ID#consumer-1| [thrd:app]: librdkafka v1.2.1 (0x10201ff) CLIENT_ID#consumer-1 initialized (builtin.features gzip,snappy,ssl,sasl,regex,lz4,sasl_gssapi,sasl_plain,sasl_scram,plugins,sasl_oauthbearer, GCC GXX PKGCONFIG INSTALL GNULD LDS LIBDL PLUGINS ZLIB SSL SASL_CYRUS HDRHISTOGRAM SNAPPY SOCKEM SASL_SCRAM SASL_OAUTHBEARER CRC32C_HW, debug 0x2000)
%7|1579623452.303|SUBSCRIBE|CLIENT_ID#consumer-1| [thrd:main]: Group "GROUP_NAME_CONNECT5": subscribe to new subscription of 1 topics (join state init)
%7|1579623452.303|REBALANCE|CLIENT_ID#consumer-1| [thrd:main]: Group "GROUP_NAME_CONNECT5" is rebalancing in state init (join-state init) without assignment: unsubscribe
%7|1579623453.441|JOIN|CLIENT_ID#consumer-1| [thrd:main]: Group "GROUP_NAME_CONNECT5": postponing join until up-to-date metadata is available
%7|1579623453.443|REJOIN|CLIENT_ID#consumer-1| [thrd:main]: Group "GROUP_NAME_CONNECT5": subscription updated from metadata change: rejoining group
%7|1579623453.443|REBALANCE|CLIENT_ID#consumer-1| [thrd:main]: Group "GROUP_NAME_CONNECT5" is rebalancing in state up (join-state init) without assignment: group rejoin
%7|1579623455.300|JOIN|CLIENT_ID#consumer-1| [thrd:main]: sasl_ssl://xxxx/159: Joining group "GROUP_NAME_CONNECT5" with 1 subscribed topic(s)
%7|1579623458.305|ASSIGNOR|CLIENT_ID#consumer-1| [thrd:main]: Group "GROUP_NAME_CONNECT5": "range" assignor run for 1 member(s)
%7|1579623458.309|ASSIGN|CLIENT_ID#consumer-1| [thrd:main]: Group "GROUP_NAME_CONNECT5": new assignment of 8 partition(s) in join state wait-assign-rebalance_cb
%7|1579623458.309|OFFSET|CLIENT_ID#consumer-1| [thrd:main]: GroupCoordinator/159: Fetch committed offsets for 8/8 partition(s)
%7|1579623458.312|FETCH|CLIENT_ID#consumer-1| [thrd:main]: Partition che_silo_cnsld_rpt_mthly [2] start fetching at offset 123698
%7|1579623458.313|FETCH|CLIENT_ID#consumer-1| [thrd:main]: Partition che_silo_cnsld_rpt_mthly [7] start fetching at offset 116555
%7|1579623458.465|FETCH|CLIENT_ID#consumer-1| [thrd:main]: Partition che_silo_cnsld_rpt_mthly [4] start fetching at offset 106800
%7|1579623458.484|FETCH|CLIENT_ID#consumer-1| [thrd:main]: Partition che_silo_cnsld_rpt_mthly [1] start fetching at offset 107557
%7|1579623458.485|FETCH|CLIENT_ID#consumer-1| [thrd:main]: Partition che_silo_cnsld_rpt_mthly [6] start fetching at offset 109805
%7|1579623458.486|FETCH|CLIENT_ID#consumer-1| [thrd:main]: Partition che_silo_cnsld_rpt_mthly [0] start fetching at offset 91465
%7|1579623458.487|FETCH|CLIENT_ID#consumer-1| [thrd:main]: Partition che_silo_cnsld_rpt_mthly [3] start fetching at offset 102042
%7|1579623458.487|FETCH|CLIENT_ID#consumer-1| [thrd:main]: Partition che_silo_cnsld_rpt_mthly [5] start fetching at offset 117214

## ran kafka-consumer-groups

../bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server xxx --command-config producer.properties --group GROUP_NAME_CONNECT5 --describe

Consumer group 'GROUP_NAME_CONNECT5' has no active members.

## then, I run the kafka-console-consumer using the same new consumer-group (GROUP_NAME_CONNECT5). It consumes all the messages in the Topic.

../bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server xxx --command-config producer.properties --group GROUP_NAME_CONNECT5 --describe
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: If the number of processors is expected to increase from one, then you should configure the number of parallel GC threads appropriately using -XX:ParallelGCThreads=N
Consumer group 'GROUP_NAME_CONNECT5' has no active members.

TOPIC                    PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG             CONSUMER-ID     HOST            CLIENT-ID
che_silo_cnsld_rpt_mthly 1          112644          112644          0               -               -               -
che_silo_cnsld_rpt_mthly 5          123099          123099          0               -               -               -
che_silo_cnsld_rpt_mthly 0          95715           95715           0               -               -               -
che_silo_cnsld_rpt_mthly 3          106932          106932          0               -               -               -
che_silo_cnsld_rpt_mthly 4          112588          112588          0               -               -               -
che_silo_cnsld_rpt_mthly 7          122047          122047          0               -               -               -
che_silo_cnsld_rpt_mthly 2          129940          129940          0               -               -               -
che_silo_cnsld_rpt_mthly 6          115050          115050          0               -               -               -

## Then I produce some new messages into the topic and run the python-consumer...and, this time the python-consumer runs successfully !

%7|1579624630.644|INIT|CLIENT_ID#consumer-1| [thrd:app]: librdkafka v1.2.1 (0x10201ff) CLIENT_ID#consumer-1 initialized (builtin.features gzip,snappy,ssl,sasl,regex,lz4,sasl_gssapi,sasl_plain,sasl_scram,plugins,sasl_oauthbearer, GCC GXX PKGCONFIG INSTALL GNULD LDS LIBDL PLUGINS ZLIB SSL SASL_CYRUS HDRHISTOGRAM SNAPPY SOCKEM SASL_SCRAM SASL_OAUTHBEARER CRC32C_HW, debug 0x2000)
%7|1579624630.648|SUBSCRIBE|CLIENT_ID#consumer-1| [thrd:main]: Group "GROUP_NAME_CONNECT5": subscribe to new subscription of 1 topics (join state init)
%7|1579624630.648|REBALANCE|CLIENT_ID#consumer-1| [thrd:main]: Group "GROUP_NAME_CONNECT5" is rebalancing in state init (join-state init) without assignment: unsubscribe
%7|1579624631.807|JOIN|CLIENT_ID#consumer-1| [thrd:main]: Group "GROUP_NAME_CONNECT5": postponing join until up-to-date metadata is available
%7|1579624631.808|REJOIN|CLIENT_ID#consumer-1| [thrd:main]: Group "GROUP_NAME_CONNECT5": subscription updated from metadata change: rejoining group
%7|1579624631.808|REBALANCE|CLIENT_ID#consumer-1| [thrd:main]: Group "GROUP_NAME_CONNECT5" is rebalancing in state up (join-state init) without assignment: group rejoin
%7|1579624633.644|JOIN|CLIENT_ID#consumer-1| [thrd:main]: sasl_ssl://cilhdkfs0304.sys.cigna.com:9095/159: Joining group "GROUP_NAME_CONNECT5" with 1 subscribed topic(s)
%7|1579624636.650|ASSIGNOR|CLIENT_ID#consumer-1| [thrd:main]: Group "GROUP_NAME_CONNECT5": "range" assignor run for 1 member(s)
%7|1579624636.654|ASSIGN|CLIENT_ID#consumer-1| [thrd:main]: Group "GROUP_NAME_CONNECT5": new assignment of 8 partition(s) in join state wait-assign-rebalance_cb
%7|1579624636.654|OFFSET|CLIENT_ID#consumer-1| [thrd:main]: GroupCoordinator/159: Fetch committed offsets for 8/8 partition(s)
%7|1579624636.656|FETCH|CLIENT_ID#consumer-1| [thrd:main]: Partition che_silo_cnsld_rpt_mthly [0] start fetching at offset 91465
%7|1579624636.656|FETCH|CLIENT_ID#consumer-1| [thrd:main]: Partition che_silo_cnsld_rpt_mthly [1] start fetching at offset 107557
%7|1579624636.656|FETCH|CLIENT_ID#consumer-1| [thrd:main]: Partition che_silo_cnsld_rpt_mthly [2] start fetching at offset 123698
%7|1579624636.656|FETCH|CLIENT_ID#consumer-1| [thrd:main]: Partition che_silo_cnsld_rpt_mthly [3] start fetching at offset 102042
%7|1579624636.656|FETCH|CLIENT_ID#consumer-1| [thrd:main]: Partition che_silo_cnsld_rpt_mthly [4] start fetching at offset 106800
%7|1579624636.656|FETCH|CLIENT_ID#consumer-1| [thrd:main]: Partition che_silo_cnsld_rpt_mthly [5] start fetching at offset 117214
%7|1579624636.656|FETCH|CLIENT_ID#consumer-1| [thrd:main]: Partition che_silo_cnsld_rpt_mthly [6] start fetching at offset 109805
%7|1579624636.656|FETCH|CLIENT_ID#consumer-1| [thrd:main]: Partition che_silo_cnsld_rpt_mthly [7] start fetching at offset 116555

Comment: Please show your code and the configurations

Comment: Are you using Kafka authorization (ACLs)?

Comment: added code, so hopefully makes more sense now ?

Comment: Did you already try to debug your consumer? To debug your consumer, you should add a key to kafkaConsumerConfig: "debug": "consumer"

Comment: You didn't set `auto.offset.reset`... Can you consume something with Python then use `kafka-consumer-groups` to describe it? Also, you're doing nothing with the polled message, and you may want to poll for longer than a second

Comment: @cricket_007 I edited my question. I will use a longer poll-time to check if it makes any difference. Also,(ffosilva) I will add a key to kafkaConsumerConfig: "debug": "consumer"

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem is related to 'auto.offset.reset' configuration. When your consumer joins the cluster, this configuration defines from which offset your consumer will start consuming. Try putting:

```
"auto.offset.reset": "earliest"
```

This configuration will make your consumer start consuming from the first (earliest) offset/message. The default configuration is "largest", it means the consumer will start consuming when there are new messages available on the topic. Check [this](https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/blob/master/CONFIGURATION.md) for more details.

Comment: Ty. I will make this change and let you know @ffosilva